# jsecurity : how to setup permission from database?

Tags: grails, groovy, jsecurity

I'm using Jsecurity plugins on Grails and I would like to know how to setup permission for each page from the database if possible.

it's like to store the following rules:

> /home/edit/*   for Admin /home/*
>   for Users /administrator/*  for Admin
>   /menu/*        for Admin, Staff Admin

etc ...

at the moment, we did it in the conf/SecurityFilters.groovy like the following

```
menuEditing(controller:"menu"){
    before = {
        accessControl {
            role("Administrator");
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to store the rules on database instead of writing on Security Filters ?

ps: i think jsecurity changes its name to Apahce Shiro
[link text](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SHIRO/Index)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a userfilter which makes the jsecurity calls to checkPermission.
If for example you can determine authorization from controller, action and id you could use this filter

```
permissionCheck() {
    before = {
        SecurityUtils.getSubject().ceckPermission("${controller}:${action}:${id}")
    }
}
```

and a realm which checks for this permission using the database.